# datatable reload on ajax call according to selected category

Tags: php, datatable, datatables

I am using a datatable on loading the products are displaying fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

After selecting a category from a dropdown outside the table, I want to reload the table with only the products undet the selected category by calling an ajax. Can you please help?

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Comment: Take a look at this documentation. https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html